# How to assign value to variables in factory and test a method using assigned value in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angularjs-factory

I have following factory. I have changed init method for the sake of brevity, because all that matters is that it loads json data (similar to data in test) in teamsConfig.

```
var AppController = angular.module("AppController");
AppController.factory('TeamFactory', ['$http', '$q',
                           function($http, $q) {

var teamsConfig = {};
return{
        init: function() {
                $http.get('navigation/TeamsConfiguration.json').success(function(data) {
                teamsConfig = data;
            }).error(function(msg, code) {
            deferred.reject(msg);
        });

    return deferred.promise;
    },

        getCaptainName: function(team) {
        return teamsConfig[team].captainName;
    }

};
```

My Jasmine code is as below

```
describe('Test TeamCaptain',function(){
beforeEach(module('AppController'));
var ctrl,scope,http,route, routeParams,location,q,svc,factory;
beforeEach(inject(function(TeamFactory,$rootScope){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    TeamFactory.teamsConfig = {
            "India":
            {
            "captain": "Dhoni",
            "batsman": "Kohli"
            },
            "Australia":
            {
            "captain": "Clarke",
            "batsman": "Watson"
            }
        };

         factory = TeamFactory;
         }));
     it('should get the captain of the team.',function(){
         var captain= '';
         var team = 'India';
         captain = factory.getCaptainName(team);
         expect(captain).toEqual('Dhoni');
    });
}));
```

While running tests, I'm getting error
--TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object evaluating 'teamsConfig[team].captainName'

I have changed the code from original, it may have small errors/typos.

Comment: you have not defined deffered object.

Comment: Where do you expose a property teams on TeamFactory.teams ? Shouldn't you set teamsConfig ?

Comment: @BorisCharpentier, corrected. thanks, but that is not the issue. It was typo while copying code from app to Stackoverflow.

Comment: console.log(teamsConfig) if that looks okay console.log(teamsConfig['India']) if that also works blame the leprechaun.  Also check out $httpBackend you can setup $httpBackend.when('GET', 'navigation/TeamsConfiguration.json').respond({/*your expected JSON response here*/});

Comment: Your service doesn't get its teams from its teamsConfig field. It gets them from a private local variable of the closure where the service is defined. This variable is not accessible from outside of the closure. You should mock the httpBackend and make it return fake json, then call init(), flush the httpBackend, end finally call the getCaptainName() function.